# Listen for apply.daterangepicker event in vue component

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-daterangepicker, vue-events

I think I get how to listen for a click event, but I'm trying to determine how I listen for a custom  event for the `bootstrap-daterangepicker` plugin.

In jquery, you'd normally listen for this event with something like:

```
 $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
          $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
      });
```

So the event that I'm supposed to be listening for according to the [bootstrap-daterangepicker docs](http://www.daterangepicker.com) is `apply.daterangepicker`.

I figured I need to bind the event to my element with I would assume a custom event based on the docs:

`<date-range-picker v-on:apply.daterangepicker="doSomething"></date-range-picker>`

So then in my vue component I have this:

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group drp-container">
        <input type="text" class="form-control drp" name="daterangepicker">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import moment from 'moment';
  import daterangepicker from 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';

export default {
  name: 'date-range-picker',
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  mounted() {
      $('.drp').daterangepicker({
          ranges: {
              'Today': [moment(), moment()],
              'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
              'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
              'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
              'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
              'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
          },
          alwaysShowCalendars: true,
          buttonClasses: "btn",
          applyClass: "btn-brand-green",
          cancelClass: "btn-brand-red",
          showDropdowns: true,
          autoApply: true,
          opens: 'right',
          maxDate: moment()
      });
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      console.log('do something');
      console.log(picker.startDate);
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

I'm just trying to sort out how all this is supposed to work as I'm new to vue, so I'd be happy to just be able to console.log the dates when a date range is selected, but ultimately a more complete solution would  be based on this being a DateRangePicker self-contained child component that passes its events and data(?) back to a parent component.

So my quick-and-dirty question would be, how can I just get this working to console.log the selected values?

The end goal question would be, how can I emit this event back to a parent component so I can do something with it.

**UPDATE**

I've realized I placed the event binding on the main reference to the component, rather than on the underlying html element, so if I change that and just use a simple click event, I can get the `doSomething()` method to fire at least, so that's a step in the right direction.

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently `v-on:click` works, but `v-on:change` or any other event I try doesn't, so now I'm extra confused about vue.

**UPDATE 3**

Found [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39991519/4113027) and I'm not sure if this is the right method or not. It works, but it seems duplicative. I'm registering an event listener on `mounted()` that calls updateValue(), but then it also has `v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"`. Is this right? How is this not just duplicating the event listener?

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group drp-container">
        <input type="text" class="form-control drp" name="daterangepicker" v-bind:value="value" v-on:input="udpateValue($event.target.value)">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  import moment from 'moment';
  import daterangepicker from 'bootstrap-daterangepicker';

export default {
  name: 'date-range-picker',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  mounted() {
      var self = this;
      $(this.$el).daterangepicker({
          ranges: {
              'Today': [moment(), moment()],
              'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
              'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
              'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
              'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
              'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
          },
          alwaysShowCalendars: true,
          buttonClasses: "btn",
          applyClass: "btn-brand-green",
          cancelClass: "btn-brand-red",
          showDropdowns: true,
          autoApply: true,
          opens: 'right',
          maxDate: moment()
      }).on('apply.daterangepicker', function(e, picker){
        let start = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let end = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let dates = {};
        dates.start = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        dates.end = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');  
        self.updateValue(dates);
      });
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue: function(value) {
      console.log(value);
      //this.$emit('input', dates);
    }
  },
  watch: {

  }
}

</script>
```